# Fuel-SDK: How to upsert (UpdateAdd) DataExtension row

Tags: marketing-cloud, php, fuel-sdk

PHP's startker-kit has an *UpdateAdd* save action, which basically inserts a row if its ID doesn't exist and updates it if the id exists.

Is there an equivalent in PHP's Fuel-SDK? Or do I need to write code to check if the given row id already exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question: No.

I got around by doing a `post` and checking if an error is returned
complaining about key constraints, if so do a `patch`.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the upsert part on FuelSDK core (ET_Patch class __construct) isn't used on patch().  Also a known feature request/update on https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp/issues/48.

Instead, I use a filter on a Row->get() to do my thing.

```
    $row = new ET_DataExtension_Row();
    $row->authStub = $client;       
    $row->filter = ['Property' => 'SubscriberKey', 'SimpleOperator' => 'equals', 'Value' => 123920932];        
    $row->props = ["SubscriberKey"]; 
    $response = $row->get();

    if (!count($response->results)) {
        // use post            
    } else {
        // use patch
    }
```